# Impossible nested logical expressions in neo4j Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am experimenting with neo4j cypher query language and I run into problem with these expressions:

This is valid query expression and returns true:

```
start n=node(3) return 1 <> 2
```

But this is not:

```
start n=node(3) return (1 <> 2) = true
```

in my opinion it should return also true, but it returns error:

**Error: string matching regex `\z' expected but`=' found**

I tried similar queries like (which also fail):

```
start n = node(3) return not(true = true) = true
start n = node(3) return (true <> true) = true
```

I am testing queries on http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-where.html when I click on **try this query live**

Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Nice catch... I think this may be fixed in an upcoming build when they redo the parser.

Comment: please file a bug report so it isn't lost, https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues

Comment: I reported it, https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/843 I don't think it will be fixed shortly..

Answer (score 0):

There does appear to be a workaround available.

```
START n=node(3) 
WITH (1<>2) AS a 
WHERE a = TRUE 
RETURN a
```

Answer (score 0):

Since at least Neo4j Server 3.5.14 this works.